# WPF - How to use Badge in Mahapps HamburgerMenuItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro, hamburger-menu

Quick question for who known WPF:

How to add a badge in a Mahapps HamburgerMenuItem?

I use this template:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem}">
                <Grid Height="48">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                            <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{Binding Icon}" />
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>

                    </ContentControl>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Label}" />
                </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And here is my Hamburger Items:

```
            <Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>

                <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem Icon="{StaticResource appbar_home_variant}" Label="Home">
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                        <Grid Name="HomeView"></Grid>
                    </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem>

                <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem Icon="{StaticResource appbar_people_status}" Label="Private" >
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                        <Grid Name="PrivateView"></Grid>
                    </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem>

                <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem Icon="{StaticResource appbar_page_onenote}" Label="Notes">
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                        <Grid Name="NotesView"></Grid>
                    </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem>

                <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem Icon="{StaticResource appbar_cog}" Label="Settings">
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                        <Grid Name="SettingsView"></Grid>
                    </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem>

            </Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>

        </Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
```

Here what I am looking for:

[HamburgerMenu Badge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEQ8Y.png)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

As I found [here](https://mahapps.com/controls/badged-control.html)

You can wrap them arround your Icon.

```
<Controls:Badged Badge="{Binding Path=BadgeValue}" BadgePlacementMode="BottomRight">
    <!-- Control to wrap goes here -->
    <Button>
        <iconPacks:PackIconFontAwesome Kind="CommentOutline"/>
    </Button>
</Controls:Badged>
```

In your example it would be:

```
<Controls:Badged Badge="{Binding Path=BadgeValue}">
    <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem Icon="{StaticResource appbar_home_variant}" Label="Home">
            <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                <Grid Name="HomeView"></Grid>
            </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
    </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem>
</Controls:Badged>
```

Comment: Hi Julian, Thank you for your answer. I tried it but it seems that you cant apply a badge directly on a HamburgerMenuIconItem. It return an error.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible. But it will get cut and does not look very good IMO

### Example closed:

[image]

### Example opened:

[image]

How to get it?:
Just wrap your Icon in the `DataTemplate` with a `Badge`:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="HamburgerMenuItem" DataType="{x:Type Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem}">
        <DockPanel Height="48" LastChildFill="True">
            <Controls:Badged x:Name="IconPart"
                                Width="48"
                                Badge="?"
                                BadgeBackground="Red"
                                DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                <Image Margin="12"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Source="{Binding Glyph}"
                        Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            </Controls:Badged>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextPart"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="16"
                        Text="{Binding Label}" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=PanePlacement}" Value="Right">
                <Setter TargetName="IconPart" Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Right" />
                <Setter TargetName="TextPart" Property="Margin" Value="8,0,0,0" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

You can modify this to your needs.

**UPDATE**: Here are additional information from the maintainer of MahApps: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/3800#issuecomment-631103384

I hope this helps and happy coding

Tim